# Does .pbix file also contain data?

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I'd like to send my pbix file to a colleague to make him work on that.
Does the pbix file also contain the data or is it just the visualization and they have to load data by themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually yes it does contain the data.  The only choice for the majority of sources, and the default choice for the other sources is to **import** data.

If you need further info, this doco explains those options in detail. You could just skim the overview at the top to get the broad picture:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-directquery-about

Also, if you have a **.pbix** file and you want to remove the data, you can use **File / Export** to save it as a Template (**.pbit** file). Anyone opening the **.pbit** file will have to connect to the data sources and run a successful refresh before they can see the data.

Comment: Your reference link is about 10 pages.  What information from your reference link is relevant to the user?

Comment: Yes good point - not everyone is a Power BI nut like me :-) . I'll edit my answer to clarify.